# 80's-90's movie with a brains-powered spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie when I was young on the Sci-Fi network. It might have been made in the early 90's, late 80's. This movie was not an anime or animation, it had real actors. I think it might have been a trilogy.

Its main character was an obese women captured(?) along with a bunch of other people and she was sent to a RM on a metal table that made her thin and beautiful. She also teamed up with a robot head that fell in love with her (and was kinda pervy) and would unlock the doors for her to escape this place she had been captured.

I also remember there was a spaceship that had 12-8 brains that 'talked' and powered the space ship(?). The space ship and brains were important to the movie but I don't know why.

There were also these worm alien monsters that had been released in this futuristic gladiator arena.

Answer (score 15):

This is the German sci-fi TV serial [*Lexx*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx) which ran for five seasons from 1997 to 2002.

[image: Zev pre-transformation]

During the pilot episode the obese woman, Zev/Xev Bellringer, was a prisoner made thin and conventionally attractive to serve as a sex slave/robot, but the process was interrupted, and she retained her own sense of self. This character was played by at least three actors during the show's tenure: the two during the pilot, and another when the second actor left the show, and the story was written to explain the character's physical transformation. Zev appears above pre-transformation, and below left post-first transformation holding 790. Xev post-second transformation appears below right.

[image: Zev Bellringer post-transformation 1] [image: Xev Bellringer post-transformation 2]

The robot head obsessed with Zev/Xev is 790, and is accurately described in the OP's question.

The spaceship is a living organism and is the titular *Lexx* (pictured below). Much of the show's situational comedy derives from the experiences of the main characters living inside a living ship (there are some parallels with [*Farscape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farscape)'s Moya).

[image: Lexx]

The two other main character's were the chauvinistic, ultra-dweeby & pervy captain of the Lexx: Stanley H. Tweedle (below left), and the somewhat undead emo Brunnen-G space-warrior Kai (below right).

[image: Stanley H. Tweedle] [image: Kai]

Comment: Wasn't there also a movie? Or was it just like an extended pilot?

Comment: Hmm apparently not. Very strange I would have sworn I saw something that was a movie.

Comment: You're memories are correct, @DRF. The First season's episodes had a runtime of 90 minutes, giving a movie-like fee (compare the wiki link)l.

Comment: @sum1stolemyname Ahh thank you very much. That explains both me remembering a movie and me feeling it ended strangely.:D

Comment: You didn't mention the brains. Those were the former His Shadows, if I remember correctly, though I don't remember clearly what their significance was.

Comment: @Nathaniel Nor do I mention the worms... I don't recall off the top of my head, and don't want to go down the rabbit hole of rewatching *Lexx*. :)

Comment: Sounds like a mashup of two Anne McCaffery stories/series... Brain/Brawn ships and her standalone first novel Restoree.